# Extending error message variable

Tags: php, forms, validation

Right now I just have one error message variable that pulls the item name from the form input field that is creating the validation error. So if I only had one letter typed in the 'firstname' input field the error message should show up like this...

firstname must be a minimum of 2 characters.

Which is fine, but I want to create new variables, so that I can put something like

```
$firstname_validate_error
```

next to the firstname input field and if that input field is throwing the error for the error to come up next to that field.

Is there a way to do this with the code I have without making this a huge task? I'm not sure how to structure a variable to do this with my validate class.

I am getting my validation errors from this:

```
} else {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                    $error;
                }
```

Is there a way I can structure this so I can put some kind of error variable next to each input field in the form so if that input field is throwing the validation error, the error message comes up?

```
if(Input::exists()) {
   if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    if(Input::exists()) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'firstname' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'lastname' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'email' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'phone_number' => array (
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 7,
                'max' => 15
            ),
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 4,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            )

        ));
        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {
                $user->create(array(
                    'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                    'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                $success = "You have successfully created an account. We will notify you once the account has been approved. Then you will be able to login.";
                echo $success;
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                    $error;
                }
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

My validate class that pertains to this.

```
public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);
            $item = escape($item);

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                $this->addError("{$item} is required");
            } else if(!empty($value)) {
                switch($rule) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                        if($check->count()) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                        }
                    break;
```

My form is like this..

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="firstname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('lastname')); ?>" required>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use some magic functions like:

```
 $validate = new <classname of your validation class>;
 ....
 $validate->field_firstname();
```

which is obviously not defined. `firstname` matches to the array of field definitions in your validation class. Catch that with something like

```
    public function __call($key, $params = array(null))
    {
        if ( substr($key, 0, 6) == "field_" )
        {
            // extract field name
            $field = substr($key, 6);

            // validate $field now:
            // ...

            return;
        }

        throw new Exception('Unknown method ' . $key);

    }
```